# Is there a way to manually corrupt a file?

Tags: java, file-io, io

I have a process in which very sporadically I'm creating files which for reasons that I can't yet figure out I get a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: File is not a normal file." exception even though the file appears (in the file manager and text editor) to be entirely healthy.  So, I'm trying to recreate this error and see how I can deal with it but to do that I need to manually create a file that would raise this exception, and I have no clue what I could manually do to a file to have it suddenly become "broken" in this way.

I realize that whatever I will do to the file is not the same thing that is wrong with the files that are throwing my exception, but for the purpose of writing testable code to verify that my safeguarding code works, that won't matter... I just need a broken file.  I guess I could just throw the exception manually in some random cycle, but I was hoping I could get this to be more "realistic".

All help appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to debug the actual issue instead of asking us how to recreate a test case? Just create a corrupt file yourself using a hex editor if you want to that badly, but more important would be to figure out what isn't getting flushed properly.

Comment: @Platinum Azure... yeah, I'd LOVE to find the culprit, but as I said, this happens very rarely on a production app. When I have it running through a debugger and logging it *never happens. I just get reports from the field that once in a blue moon it does, and I need to simply work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to corrupt an existing file just write a function that opens the file and scrambles the bytes. You can also do this with a hex editor. If you want to generate garbage files you can just create a new file and write a random.nextBytes() in to it.

Comment: would `random.nextBytes()` actually corrupt the file (meaning, make it so that when I call File() on it it will raise the exception in my question), or will it just add garbage to the end?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspoke. File() does work... passing the result to a FilePart object is what fails.

Comment: It's definitely 100% NOT creating a directory. If it was, how could I then look at it in the File Manager? Is that something that's feasible? That Java thinks it's a directory, but the file system shows it to me as a regular file (that I can rename and modify the contents of)?

Comment: I actually did rename it and then it was processed correctly (which includes its deletion) so the one sample I had is now gone... Otherwise, I'd be happy to share it, it's not sensitive, it's just a bit of xml.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you may be looking the wrong way, especially if the file is actually not corrupted according to text editors.
You should have posted the entire stack trace. I suspect that the issue is not with the file but with the path name.
Have you tried the result of [File#isfile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29) at the point you get the exception?
From javadoc (my emphasis)

> public boolean isFile()
>
> Tests whether the file denoted by this abstract pathname is a
>   **normal file**. ***A file is normal if*** it is not a directory and, in
>   addition, satisfies other system-dependent criteria. Any non-directory
>   file created by a Java application is guaranteed to be a normal file.

I suspect that `File#isfile()` would return `false` prior to the exception and you should look into this API instead of trying to corrupt the file

Comment: The issue is that this is happening extremely rarely in a process that is basically 100% working.  So... I'm entirely stumped as to why and how and when this happens, and unfortunately, it doesn't happen to any of my devices under any test circumstances that I can think to put it through. It ONLY happens in the field, on devices that I don't have access to.  I don't have stack traces, only the logging that I have put in myself trying to catch the culprit. It definitely happens when I try to pass the file as a parameter to FilePart() for uploading.  I will definitely add the isFile() test.

Comment: --however, I'm curious how it can fail the isFile() test when I can SEE the file (and read its apparently correct contents) in the file system manager!

Comment: @Dr.Dredel:Whether you see it is not relevant.You can get this exception if the `SecurityManager` sees that there is no READ permissions for the file

Answer (score 2):

A corrupted file is still a file. A corrupted Word document for example is still a file but cannot be opened using a word processor because it's content is not readable.

The exception is thrown here :

```
public FilePartSource(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
66          this.file = file;
67          if (file != null) {
68              if (!file.isFile()) {
69                  throw new FileNotFoundException("File is not a normal file.");
70              }
71              if (!file.canRead()) {
72                  throw new FileNotFoundException("File is not readable.");
73              }
74              this.fileName = file.getName();       
75          }
76      }
```

and occurs when your file is not a file, but rather something else (a directory? a link to an inexistant file?)